# jquery functions arent called on click

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.poga').css('cursor','pointer');

      $("#poga1").click(function() {
      var n= "poga1";
        alert ("pēc piereģistrē " + n);
      });
      $("#poga2").click(function() {

        var n= "poga2";  
        alert ("pēc piereģistrē " + n);
      });

      $(".poga").click(function(){
         $(".poga").animate({borderBottomWidth:'1'});
         $(this).animate({borderBottomWidth:'0'});
         alert ("n ir vienāds ar " + n);
         switch(n)
    {
    case poga1:
      $("#ChangeContent").html("Pirmā poga nospiesta.");
      break;
    case poga2:
     $("#ChangeContent").html("Otrā poga nospiesta.");
      break;
    default:
      $("#ChangeContent").html("Trešā vai ceturtā poga nospiesta.");
    }

     return false;
});

});
```

So, i've got this javascript function that is supposed to dynamically change the text after pressing a button. "poga" means button in my language. Since i'm a beginner in jquery, i'm trying to keep it simple.

```
  $("#poga1").click(function() {
  var n= "poga1";
    alert ("pēc piereģistrē " + n);
  });
  $("#poga2").click(function() {

    var n= "poga2";  
    alert ("pēc piereģistrē " + n);
  });
```

When button 1 is clicked, make n equal "poga1", when button 2 is clicked, make n equal "poga2"

```
  $(".poga").click(function(){
     $(".poga").animate({borderBottomWidth:'1'});
     $(this).animate({borderBottomWidth:'0'});
     alert ("n ir vienāds ar " + n);
     switch(n)
{
case poga1:
  $("#ChangeContent").html("Pirmā poga nospiesta.");
  break;
case poga2:
 $("#ChangeContent").html("Otrā poga nospiesta.");
  break;
default:
  $("#ChangeContent").html("Trešā vai ceturtā poga nospiesta.");
}
```

When any of the buttons are clicked (all of the buttons have this class), animate a little bit and change the content of the div that's named "ChangeContent".

For some reason, i don't even get the alert in the last function, although before i added the first two functions that register n, the last function was working.

My question is why the last function that is supposed to work when i click a specific class doesn't work?

Comment: If you have a fiddle showing what you're trying to do (markup as well as JavaScript), it will be easier to debug.

Comment: heres the fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/j6ULQ/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are facing is to do with variable scope.  You are declaring `n` inside the click functions, so it does not exist outside them.  Look at this code...

```
var n;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.poga').css('cursor','pointer');

    $("#poga1").click(function() {
        n = "poga1";
        alert ("pec pieregistre " + n);
    });

    $("#poga2").click(function() {
        n = "poga2";  
        alert ("pec pieregistre " + n);
    });

    $(".poga").click(function(){
        $(".poga").animate({borderBottomWidth:'1'});
        $(this).animate({borderBottomWidth:'0'});
        alert ("n ir vienads ar " + n);
        switch(n)
        {
            case "poga1":
                $("#ChangeContent").html("Pirma poga nospiesta.");
                break;
            case "poga2":
                $("#ChangeContent").html("Otra poga nospiesta.");
                break;
            default:
                $("#ChangeContent").html("Treša vai ceturta poga nospiesta.");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

In that, `n` is declared outside the click functions, so you can assign values to it and it will persist in other functions.

**Edit:**

I've updated your jsfiddle example here...

http://jsfiddle.net/j6ULQ/2/

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that!  I think the combination of this plus my answer will get you there (What I pointed out is in the code example, but not it in the text)

Comment: You can move the ```var n``` into the ready function and avoid polluting the global scope.

Comment: I did spot that myself, but didn't mention it.  It's fixed in my code above and in the updated jsfiddle.

Comment: @jameslafferty Of course, but I didn't want to assume it's not used anywhere else.

Comment: Thank you. I'm feeling very stupid for not thinking of that now.

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make.  Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case statement, you're testing against the values of variables named `poga1` and `poga2` instead of the string values.  Add quotes around the values so you will have

```
switch(n)
{
case 'poga1':
  $("#ChangeContent").html("Pirmā poga nospiesta.");
  break;
case 'poga2':
 $("#ChangeContent").html("Otrā poga nospiesta.");
  break;
default:
  $("#ChangeContent").html("Trešā vai ceturtā poga nospiesta.");
}
```